# Firefox can't see input text

Tags: html, css, firefox

hi i made a form and styled it with css, with all browser is just fine, all works as it should. In firefox i can't see the text that i write... I can't even select it. only select field show the text correctly.

why?

```
    .pText{
margin-top: -8px !important;
}
.codiceVerifica{
margin-top: -20px !important;
}

.codiceInserito{
margin-top: -20px !important;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-left: 4px;
width: 100% !important;
}
.textVerifica{
margin-top: -15px !important;
margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.numberBlu{
 margin-top: -29px !important;
}

.numberWhite{
 margin-top: -29px !important;
}

.colonnaDestra{
 width: 45% !important;
float:left !important;
margin-top: -40px !important;
}
.colonnaCentrale{
 width: 10% !important;
 text-align: center !important;
 float: left !important;
margin-top: -44px !important;
}
.colonnaSinistra{
 width: 45% !important;
 float:left !important;
margin-top 15px;
margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.colSinistra2{
 width: 45% !important;
 float:left !important;
margin-top: 45px !important;
background-color:red;
}

.colonnaCentraleN4{
 width: 100% !important;
 text-align: center !important;
 float: left !important;
margin-top: -58px !important;
margin-bottom: 40px !important;
}
.colonnaDestraN4{
 width: 50% !important;
float:left !important;
border-left: 3px solid #96cde8;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 35px!important;
}
.colonnaCentraleN4Inversa{
 width: 100% !important;
 text-align: center !important;
 float: left !important;
margin-bottom: 75px !important;
}
.colonnaDestra2{
width: 45% !important;
float:left !important;
text-align: end;
padding-bottom: 35px!important;
}

.colonnaDestraN42{
 width: 50% !important;
float:left !important;
border-left: 3px solid #96cde8;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 35px!important;
}

.colonnaSinistraN4{
 width: 50% !important;
 float:left !important;
border-right: 3px solid #96cde8;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 35px!important;
}


.swatch-test .btn-link{
text-decoration: none;
box-shadow: none;
font-weight: 600 !important;
}

.swatch-test .btn-link:hover, [class*="swatch-"] .swatch-test .btn-link:hover{
 text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.swatch-white-background-with-blue-elements .btn-link, [class*="swatch-"] .swatch-white-background-with-blue-elements .btn-link{
text-decoration: none;
box-shadow: none;
font-weight: 600 !important;
}

.swatch-white-background-with-blue-elements .btn-link:hover, [class*="swatch-"] .swatch-white-background-with-blue-elements .btn-link:hover{
 text-decoration: underline !important;
}

/*  
**************** form partecipate style
*/
#fp_c2_r1{
    width: 100%;
}
#fp_c2_r1_left{
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}
#fp_c2_r1_right{
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
}
#fp_c2_r1_ p{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#fp_c2_r1 input[type="text"]{
    width:240px;
        border-radius: 5px;
}
#fp_c2_r1select{
    width:240px;
border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-title{
 margin: 0;
color: #009ed7;
font-size: 32px !important;
font-family: "Lato";
font-weight: 300;
width: 70%;
line-height: 1.42857143;
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog{
transition: transform .3s ease-out; 
width:95%; 
max-width:860px !important; 
margin: 130px auto !important
}

.modal-content{
 border-radius: 8px ;
}

.styleSamexWeTrust{
padding-top: 30px !important;
}

.flex-viewport { height: auto !important; }

.captcha{
 width: 100%;
float: left;
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.codiceCaptcha{
 width:12%;
float: left;
margin-top: 6px;
}

.inserisciCodice{
 width: 88%;
float:left;
}
@media all{
.privacyBox{
 width:100%;
float:left;
margin-bottom:15px;
}
}

.checkPrivacy{
 float:left;
margin-right: 9px;
width: auto;
}

.privacyText{
 float:left;
width:auto;
font-size: 14px;
}

@media all{
.bottoneInviaForm{
 text-align: center;
width:100%;
float:left
}}

.section.has-bottom:not(.has-top):nth-child(3){
 text-align: center;
}

#text-7{
 border-left: 2px solid #96cde8 !important; 
padding-left: 40px;
min-height: 200px;
}

#swatch_social-3{
 border-left: 2px solid #96cde8 !important; 
text-align: -webkit-center;
min-height: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px){
#swatch_social-3{
width: 50%;
text-align: -webkit-center;
min-height: 200px;
float: left;
}

#text-7{
width: 50%;
padding-left: 40px;
min-height: 200px;
float: left;
}

#text-3{
width: 100%;
float: left;
text-align: -webkit-center;
}


.colonnaDestra{
 width: 100% !important;
float:left !important;
margin-top: -40px !important;
text-align: -webkit-center;
}
.colonnaCentrale{
 width: 0% !important;
}
.colonnaSinistra{
 width: 100% !important;
 float:left !important;
margin-top 15px;
margin-bottom: 45px;
text-align: -webkit-center;
}


}

@media screen and (max-width:550px){
#swatch_social-3{
width: 100%;
min-height: 200px;
 float: left;
 border-top: 2px solid #96cde8 !important; 
border-left: none!important;
text-align: -webkit-center;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 0px !important;
}

#text-7{
width: 100%;
min-height: 200px;
 float: left;
 border-top: 2px solid #96cde8 !important; 
border-left: none!important;
text-align: -webkit-center;
padding: 0px !important;
}

#text-3{
width: 100%;
float: left;
text-align: -webkit-center;
}

}

.formPartecipa{

}
.formPartecipa input[type="text"], input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="tel"], input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="email"], input[type="file"], input[type="file"]:focus{
height: 4px;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 8px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #96cde8;
width: 100%;
font-size: 13px !important;
line-height: 27px !important;

}

.formPartecipa textarea, textarea:focus{
padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
border-radius: 8px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #96cde8;
width: 100%;
font-size: 13px !important;
line-height: 27px !important;

}

.formPartecipa label{
font-size: 13px !important;
margin:0px;
}

.formPartecipa input[type="file"], input[type="file"]:focus{
padding: 1px 10px 0px 10px;
height: 34px;
}



.select-wrap{
border-radius: 8px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #96cde8;
width: 100%;
font-size: 13px !important;
line-height: 26px;
heigh:34px;
}


.select-wrap:after, select{
line-height: 27px !important;
}
.attivita{
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.ragioneSociale{
 width: 100%;
float: left;
}


.settore{
width: 100%;
float: left;
}



.wpcf7-form-control-wrap{
 padding-right: 15px !important;
line-height: 27px !important;
}

.nome{
 width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.cognome{
 width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.citta{
 width: 70%;
float: left;
}

.cap{
 width: 30%;
float: left;
}

.indirizzo{
 width: 70%;
float: left;
}

.numero-civico{
 width: 30%;
float: left;
}

.email{
 width: 60%;
float: left;
}

.sito-web{
 width: 40%;
float: left;
}

.messaggio{
 width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.recapito-telefonico{
 width: 100%;
float: left;
}
.origine{
 width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.specifica-origine{
 width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.uploadVisuraCamerale{
width: 100%;
float:left;
}

.bilancio{
width: 100%;
float:left;
}
```

this is part of the css... as you see there's no color information in it. and if I add color:red; it still won't show it. what can it be? it just happen on firefox

Comment: Well you have some typos "textare" and I suspect the CSs isn't quite specific enough. We need to see a demo to narrow this down.

Comment: Actually, we need the code here...not in a link that might go away in time.

Comment: We only need the **relevant** HTML & CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visible part is the padding space, the text is lower.

Your padding is to important and you fix the height.
You must remove the height property to fix your problem.